# Reporting tool for Excel

Tags: .net, reporting, export-to-excel

We are developing a Asp.net 3.5 web application for a rather strict environment. We need to generate reports and *export them to Excel*.

Please suggest some tool which we don't need to install into GAC. Because to install anything into GAC we have to go through many hurdles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://www.codeplex.com/ExcelPackage

It has some limitations, like no proper support for graphs, but you can get around that by predefining the graphs in a template file.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you don't want to generate the reports in a custom application could be to use Excel and call a web service to return the required data. http://weblogs.asp.net/erobillard/archive/2005/07/22/420289.aspx